# Excel - counting people that meet a criterion and have one or another value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large dataset that is similar to the below:

```
A   B   C   D  
1   X  .5   0   
2   X   0   0  
3   Y  .5   1   
4   X   1  .5
```

I would like to count the number of instances for which column B = X and the value in column C or D is greater than 0.

So for the above case the answer would be 2.

As this count is part of a larger output table, I'd like to not use a pivot.

I've tried fumbling around with countifs and frequency to no avail.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please show the COUNTIFS you tried.

Comment: I've tried two COUNTIFs but neither gets there:

=COUNTIFS(B:A5,"X",C2:C5,">0",D2:D5,">0")
Which gave a count too low 

and I tried
=COUNTIFS(B:A5,"X",C2:C5,">0")+COUNTIFS(B:A5,"X",D2:D5,">0")
which double counted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B="X")*(((C>0)+(D>0))>0))
```

**Edit**: *Explanation* In this kind of formula, you can consider that multiplication does an `AND` operation, and addition does an `OR` operation.  Of course, with the `OR` operation, since both C and D could be > 0, you need to test that summation to ensure that you are not double counting.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked perfectly and was nice and neat!

Comment: @ap603 I added a bit of an explanation.  If this has solved your problem, I would appreciate it if you could mark my response as the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible outcomes that can produce an accurate total count when summed together.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B2:B5, "X", C2:C5, ">0", D2:D5, "<=0"),
     COUNTIFS(B2:B5, "X", C2:C5, "<=0", D2:D5, ">0"),
     COUNTIFS(B2:B5, "X", C2:C5, ">0", D2:D5, ">0"))
```